# Dismiss Dialog when user is at top and scrolled down

Tags: android, listview

I would like to dismiss the dialog when the user is at top of the layout and scrolls down. This is my code so far:

XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/White">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.99"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/hello"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_weight="0.01"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/listViewDialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried many things like on scroll listener on the listview but this detects only when the user scrolled to item 0. But I want to dismiss the dialog when the user is at the top of the full layout because there is a textview above the listview..

Comment: At first I recommend you use RecyclerView y and show more code please.

Comment: What code do you want to see?

Comment: The implementation you're trying to hide dialog.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @R.Adang I marked the answer :) Using the recyclerview and call the function findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition(). But I guess you can use a listview and check if the first visible item is equals to 0, then you should get the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a RecyclerView with a LayoutManager instead of a ListView. This LayoutManager has a function called `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()`. This returns the first completely visible item in your RecyclerView. So this will return 0 if it is at the top of the list. Add this in your ScrolListener and you are set :)